# Language change not getting affected on the text validator

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, localization, uitextfield

I am developing a multi lingual app that changes the language of the entire app through a drop down menu. The home screen has a number of textfields with validators applied that show error messages if the input in these text fields are wrong. So, at the change of language, everything else is working fine except these error messages. I am using the following two libraries:
https://github.com/dhawaldawar/TextFieldValidator for the text field validation And http://createdineden.com/blog/post/language-changer-in-app-language-selection-in-ios/ for localisation. I am attaching a screenshot in which the selected language is English but the error message is showing up in Persian.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it by relaunching the app. In iOS, LTR and RTL localisation will be reflected once app  relaunched.

Comment: The same is happening for German, Spanish and Albanian too. Its not about LTR and RTL localisation.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the Storyboard file not being correctly localised.

Did you localise the Storyboard file? If so, are all the languages present?

[image]